# Portable code for deprecated userInfo dictionary key (Cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, warnings, portability

In Mac OSX 10.6, the [NSErrorFailingURLStringKey](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSErrorFailingURLStringKey) userInfo dictionary key is deprecated in favor of NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey. I am trying to write my program to be portable to both Mac OSX 10.5 and 10.6. For the time being, I'm just using the old key--but my compiler is giving me annoying deprecated warnings.

```
// The following causes deprecation warnings
[[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSErrorFailingURLStringKey]

// But this one won't work on OSX 10.5
[[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]
```

What is the best way to write portable code to handle deprecated userInfo dictionary keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use preprocessor directives like so:

```
#if defined(MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6) && MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6
    [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]
#else
    [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSErrorFailingURLStringKey]
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the base SDK to 10.6 and the deployment target to 10.5.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift version, you can use `NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey`:

```
if let url = error?.userInfo[NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]{
    //code
}
```